# loading entities in EF7

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have an entity with a collection inside a collection. I am having a problem loading the content of collection.

```
// Site 
public class Site{
    protected Site()
    {           
        SiteUsers = new HashSet<SiteUser>();
    }    
    public virtual ICollection<SiteUser> SiteUsers { get; set; }
}

// Site User
public class SiteUser
{
    protected SiteUser()
    {
        Roles = new HashSet<SiteUserRole>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<SiteUserRole> Roles { get; protected set; }

 }


// SiteUserRole

public class SiteUserRole
{
    protected SiteUserRole()
    {
    }

    private SiteUserRole(Guid id, SiteRoleEnum role)
    {
        Id = id;
        Role = role;
        DateCreated = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SiteRoleEnum Role { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }

    public static SiteUserRole Create(Guid id, SiteRoleEnum role)
    {
        return new SiteUserRole(id, role);
    }

}


//I put this on DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Site>().HasMany(r => r.SiteUsers);            
    }
```

When I query the site it doesnt' include the roles of siteuser
 return _context.Sites.Include(c => c.SiteUsers);

Comment: Doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. Check the executed SQL. Does it contain a join?

Comment: shouldn't your collections of SiteUsers and Roles be inside the class definitions? Is this just a typo or is this the cause of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You did not include the roles:

```
context.Sites.Include(c => c.SiteUsers).ThenInclude(su => su.Roles);
```

Comment: I'd suggest to follow general instructions. I would add primary key columns (Id) and foreign Id columns (`public SiteUser SiteUser {get;set;}` and maybe int SiteUserId). I have not seen that you can define the collection to use (Hashset). So maybe you should remove this and the `protected` from `protected set` at `ICollection<SiteUserRole>` If you want uniqueness it's better to define this at the database level.